# Go: Get path parameters from http.Request

Tags: http, go, rest, http-parameters

I'm developing a REST API with Go, but I don't know how can I do the path mappings and retrieve the path parameters from them.

I want something like this:

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/provisions/:id", Provisions) //<-- How can I map "id" parameter in the path?
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func Provisions(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //I want to retrieve here "id" parameter from request
}
```

I would like to use just `http` package instead of web frameworks, if it is possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Go 1.22, you can easily retrieve the path parameters with `r.PathValue()`. For example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
)

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/provisions/{id}", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Println("Provision ID: ", r.PathValue("id"))
    })

    mux.ServeHTTP(httptest.NewRecorder(), httptest.NewRequest("GET", "/provisions/123", nil))
    mux.ServeHTTP(httptest.NewRecorder(), httptest.NewRequest("GET", "/provisions/456", nil))
}
```

Demo in [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/EREGp_9NovG). Source: https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.PathValue

Answer (score 77):

If you don't want to use any of the multitude of the available routing packages, then you need to parse the path yourself:

Route the /provisions path to your handler

```
http.HandleFunc("/provisions/", Provisions)
```

Then split up the path as needed in the handler

```
id := strings.TrimPrefix(req.URL.Path, "/provisions/")
// or use strings.Split, or use regexp, etc.
```

Comment: Make sure to not forget to add a trailing `/` after `/provisions`

Comment: You can do this more idiomatically using the native `http.StripPrefix`, which transforms a handler directly. See answer below.

Answer (score 21):

You can use golang [gorilla/mux](https://github.com/gorilla/mux) package's router to do the path mappings and retrieve the path parameters from them.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/provisions/{id}", Provisions)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}

func Provisions(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    id, ok := vars["id"]
    if !ok {
        fmt.Println("id is missing in parameters")
    }
    fmt.Println(`id := `, id)
    //call http://localhost:8080/provisions/someId in your browser
    //Output : id := someId
}
```

Comment: Go 1.22 has implemented this natively in `net/http`, negating the need for `gorilla/mux` for this use case. See my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314975/go-get-path-parameters-from-http-request/78150629#78150629

Answer (score 3):

### **Golang read value from URL query "/template/get/123".**

I used standard gin routing and handling request parameters from context parameters.

Use this in registering your endpoint:

```
func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    g := r.Group("/api")
    {
        g.GET("/template/get/:Id", templates.TemplateGetIdHandler)
    }
    r.Run()
}
```

And use this function in handler

```
func TemplateGetIdHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    req := getParam(c, "Id")
    //your stuff
}

func getParam(c *gin.Context, paramName string) string {
    return c.Params.ByName(paramName)
}
```

### **Golang read value from URL query "/template/get?id=123".**

Use this in registering your endpoint:

```
func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    g := r.Group("/api")
    {
        g.GET("/template/get", templates.TemplateGetIdHandler)
    }
    r.Run()
}
```

And use this function in handler

```
type TemplateRequest struct {
    Id string `form:"id"`
}

func TemplateGetIdHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    var request TemplateRequest
    err := c.Bind(&request)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
    }
    //your stuff
}
```

Comment: Can you add the imports? For example, gin would be in "github.com/gin-gonic/gin" but templates?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with standard library handlers. Note [`http.StripPrefix`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#StripPrefix) accepts an `http.Handler` and returns a new one:

```
func main() {
  mux := http.NewServeMux()
  provisionsPath := "/provisions/"
  mux.Handle(
    provisionsPath,
    http.StripPrefix(provisionsPath, http.HandlerFunc(Provisions)),
  )
}

func Provisions(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  fmt.Println("Provision ID:", r.URL.Path)
}
```

See working demo on [Go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/nmqa6wdv09X).

You can also nest this behavior using submuxes; `http.ServeMux` implements `http.Handler`, so you can pass one into `http.StripPrefix` just the same.

Comment: Will still match `/provisions/123/foo`

Answer (score 2):

### [Go 1.22 has now introduced this functionality natively in `net/http`](https://go.dev/blog/routing-enhancements)

This can now be achieved by calling [`req.PathValue()`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.PathValue)

> PathValue returns the value for the named path wildcard in the [ServeMux](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ServeMux) pattern that matched the request. It returns the empty string if the request was not matched against a pattern or there is no such wildcard in the pattern.

---

A basic example on how to use `reqPathValue()` is:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()

    mux.HandleFunc("/provisions/{id}", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        idString := req.PathValue("id")
        fmt.Printf("ID: %v", idString)
    })

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", mux))
}
```