# path param in URL in GO without any web framework

Tags: go

While developing a REST api in Go, how can we use path params? meaning to say what will be the format of the URI?

```
http://localhost:8765/myapp/{param1}/entries/{param2}
```

I tried using something like this to create the route but the handler function is not getting invoked.

Please note that, i intent to use only the net/http package , not any other web framework like gorilla mux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go: Get path parameters from http.Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314975/go-get-path-parameters-from-http-request)

Answer (score 2):

What I tend to do is nested handlers. "/" is handled by the root handler. It pops the first part of the path, assigns the rest back to `req.URL.Path` (effectively acting like `StripPrefix`), determines which handler handles routes by that prefix (if any), then chains the appropriate handler. If that handler needs to parse an ID out of the path, it can, by the same mechansim - pop the first part of the path, parse it as necessary, then act.

This not only has no external dependencies, but it is faster than any router could ever be, because the routing is hard-coded rather than dynamic. Unless routing changes at runtime (which would be pretty unusual), there is no need for routing to be handled dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is why people use frameworks like [gin-gonic](https://github.com/gin-gonic) because this is not easy to do this in the [net/http](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) package IIUC.

Otherwise, you would need to `strings.Split(r.URL.Path, "/")` and work from those elements.

Comment: Ya,  i had this down with gorilla Mux. But in std lib, the net/http package couldn't allow me such flexibility. I had to do with string trimming and splitting of the url path as suggested above by you. Just wanted to confirm if there is indeed any other way to get this done with anything from the std lib. I am new to GO, pardon my ignorance. The other thing i couldn't get was to have handlers based on methods.Need to access the mothod as well from the request object it seems.

Comment: Don't worry. All golang Web developers have had the same thoughts. ;)

Answer (score 0):

With `net/http` the following would trigger when calling `localhost:8080/myapp/foo/entries/bar`

```
http.HandleFunc("/myapp/", yourHandlerFunction)
```

Then inside `yourHandlerFunction`, manually parse `r.URL.Path` to find `foo` and `bar`.

Note that if you don't add a trailing `/` it won't work. The following would only trigger when calling `localhost:8080/myapp`:

```
http.HandleFunc("/myapp", yourHandlerFunction)
```

Answer (score 0):

Go 1.22 can now handle path values.  See the Go blog article [routing-enhancements](https://go.dev/blog/routing-enhancements).  If you are listening on `http://localhost:8765` as in your example, then you would use a handler with placeholders.  You can also handle a specific http method.  For instance, you can limit the handler to the GET method:

`http.HandleFunc("GET /myapp/{param1}/entries/{param2}", handleEntries)`

```
func handleEntries(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    param1 := r.PathValue("param1")
    param2 := r.PathValue("param2")

    // do stuff with parameters
}
```

See the go docs for [PathValue](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@master#Request.PathValue) and [ServeMux](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ServeMux).