# Request Form is returning nil

Tags: go, url, mux

I'm learning golang and tried to implement a custom mix to get familiar with the language, unfortunately `req.Form` is returning `nil`.

Of course I'm running before `req.ParseForm()`.

```
func (r *Router) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    req.ParseForm()
    params := req.Form
    node, _ := r.tree.findNode(strings.Split(req.URL.Path, "/")[1:], params)
    if handler := node.methods[req.Method]; handler != nil {
        handler(w, req, params)
    }
}
```

This is the example URL I'm using via `GET http://localhost:8080/users/3`

Comment: GET request contains no body, are you trying to fetch params from URL ?

Comment: Have you tried to check error returned by `func (r *Request) ParseForm() error`?

Comment: @Зелёный Well it‘s still possible that req.Form is parsing the content when using ?a=b for example as a query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, `req.Form` should always be updated if you call `req.ParseForm`.

> For all requests, ParseForm parses the raw query from the URL and updates r.Form.

Moreover, if you take a look at the implementation of ParseForm, it does not seem to be possible for it to be `nil` after the method is executed.

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/request.go#L1238

What can indeed happen is that `req.Form` ends up being an empty map, perhaps that's what you are seeing there.

It makes sense for it to be empty if you are doing:

`GET http://localhost:8080/users/3`

Since that has no params for `ParseForm` to actually parse, so `req.Form` will end up being an empty map.

If you try this for example:

`GET http://localhost:8080/users/3?a=b`

Then you should get an entry in the map with `"a"` as a key and `["b"]` as the value.

Comment: Thanks!:) So I have to parse it to get the id of an user right?

Comment: @BilalReffas, right, see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314975/go-get-path-parameters-from-http-request
Or there are many libraries out there that can make this much easier

Comment: Thanks! Going to build my own then :)